# Color samples before clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Is there a way of colouring sample names e.g. the 'leaves' of the tree before running the cluster method?
I suspect I have a batch effect but I want to visualise this before and after batch correction.

The only thing I could find online is colouring after running the cluster analysis e.g. colour by cluster

I am using agnes to cluster:

```
library(cluster)
df_clust <- na.omit(df)
df_clust <- scale(df_clust)
df_clust<-t(df_clust)
agnes(df_clust, method = "ward")
```

Comment: Always put some part of your data as a reproducible example (dput format) to make it easier to solve.

Comment: I think I have found a work around using the tanglegram! (https://uc-r.github.io/hc_clustering)